# embed bash variable in mongodb query

Tags: bash, mongodb

I have a bash variable `$i` which has to be embed in mongo shell query to get the data by comparing date.

```
i=10
while [  "$i" -lt 12 ]; do
        mongo $MONGO_DATABASE --eval 'printjson(db.mycollection.find({"created_at":{"$lte":ISODate(2016-04-\"$i\"T09:26:31.190Z)}}).toArray())' > $OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/$FILE_NAME  
done
```

The above implementation is giving `i: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

Shell variables aren't expanded within single quotes. Use double quotes:

```
mongo "$MONGO_DATABASE" --eval "printjson...ISODate(2016-04-${i}T09:26:31.190Z)
```

You will then need to escape your usages of double quotes within the string that you are evaluating, e.g. `\"created_at\"`. You will also need to escape other usages of `$`, e.g. `\$lte`.

Alternatively, you can use single quotes around the whole command and then use something like this:

```
mongo "$MONGO_DATABASE" --eval 'printjson...ISODate(2016-04-'"$i"'T09:26:31.190Z)
```

i.e. close the single quotes, concatenate the shell variable (inside double quotes), then reopen the single quotes.